# how do I connect to a remote MariaDB server on a local network using MySQLdb module in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, xampp, mysql-python

```
import MySQLdb as db

HOST = "192.168.0.82"
PORT = 8080
USER = "blade"
PASSWORD = "rise@server12"
DB = "task_management"

#remote server connection 
config = db.connect(host=HOST, user=USER, passwd=PASSWORD, db=DB)

def view():
    conn=config
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM admin ")
    rows=cur.fetchall()
    conn.close()
    #for data in rows
    return rows


 print(view())
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Pcyber\import MySQLdb as db.py", line 8, in 
connection = db.connect(host=HOST, user=USER, passwd=PASSWORD, db=DB)
File "C:\Users\Pcyber\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb_*init*_.py", line 123, in Connect
return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Pcyber\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 185, in **init**
super().**init**(*args, **kwargs2)
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1130, "Host 'DESKTOP-HP3NTQK' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server")
[Finished in 484ms]

Comment: MariaDB is mainly equivalent to MySQL and this problem, e.g. here
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-allow-remote-access-to-mysql, might touch configuration, user name and even firewall.